# Setting value for Taxonomy field produces Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: managed-metadata, splistitem, taxonomy, list-item, updatelistitems

I have a custom `ASPX` page where the user inputs data and clicks Save to add new item to the list. The field `My Department` is a `Managed Metadata field` (single choice). The user sets the value for this field through `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` control. The problem happens when the value is supposed to be set to the new list item:

```
string departmentField = "My_x0020_Department"; //internal field name

SPListItem item = myList.Items.Add();
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = this.documentTitleTextBox.Text;
item[departmentField] = this.DepartmentTaxonomy.Text; //error fires here
item.Update();
```

The error is `ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.` If the user does not specify the value for the department, i.e. if `this.DepartmentTaxonomy.Text = string.Empty;` then there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to the problem, though not the cause. Instead of just banging down the value as string `this.DepartmentTaxonomy.Text`, I really had to go an extra mile to manually create `TaxonomyFieldValue` object.

So, getting the TaxonomyFieldValue is done in this method:

```
public TaxonomyFieldValue GetTaxonomyValue(SPList list, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    string[] fieldValueParts;
    TaxonomyField taxonomyField;
    TaxonomyFieldValue taxonomyFieldValue;

    fieldValueParts = fieldValue.Split(TaxonomyField.TaxonomyGuidLabelDelimiter);
    taxonomyField = list.Fields[fieldName] as TaxonomyField;
    taxonomyFieldValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(taxonomyField);
    taxonomyFieldValue.TermGuid = fieldValueParts[1];
    taxonomyFieldValue.Label = fieldValueParts[0];

    return taxonomyFieldValue;
}
```

And here's how I used this method:

```
string departmentField = "My_x0020_Department"; //internal field name

SPListItem item = myList.Items.Add();
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = this.documentTitleTextBox.Text;
item[departmentField] = this.GetTaxonomyValue(myList, departmentField, this.DepartmentTaxonomy.Text);
item.Update();
```

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
item[departmentField] = this.DepartmentTaxonomy.Text;
try
item[departmentField] = this.DepartmentTaxonomy.Label;

Comment: `DepartmentTaxonomy` is of type `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` and this control does not contain the Label property.